# Переживать "за" или "из-за"?

Tags: падежи, предлоги, грамотная-речь

Как правильно: *переживать за экзамен* или *переживать из-за экзамена*?
Часто можно услышать первый вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По некотором размышлении предполагаю, что *переживать за экзамен* - максимум разговорный вариант, мотивированный переносом значения "переживать за экзамен" = "за сдачу экзамена". При таком переносе экзамен, и правда, становится грамматически абстрактным понятием, наследуя это качество от "сдачи".

Более того, он едва ли не одушевленным существом становится как нечто близкое, родное, за которое переживаешь.

Так что появление в разговорном или подчеркнуто-экспрессивном стиле речи можно объяснить. Но строго говоря - вряд ли нормативно.

Comment: Спасибо, behemothus!

Answer (score 3):

> Как правильно: переживать за экзамен или переживать из-за экзамена?
>   Часто можно услышать первый вариант.

Говорят и [**так**](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=I36_VpHrAsuy6ASx5oAw#q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks), и [**так**](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=eH6_VvyRIeWy6ATw-Z2IBA#q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks)… Я бы предпочёл вариант с предлогом ***из-за***.

Как это ни странно, но слово *переживать* в значении "волноваться" — сравнительно новое.

Из одного из ответов [***справочной службы Грамоты.ру:***](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=274568)

> ...в 1960-х и начале 1970-х – употребление слова *переживать* без
>   дополнения в значении 'волноваться' (я переживаю) было новым,
>   непривычным и вызывало некоторое отторжение у носителей языка
>   (особенно старшего поколения). Об этом новом употреблении писал и
>   Корней Чуковский в книге «Живой как жизнь» (1962):
>
> «...Молодежью стал по-новому ощущаться глагол *переживать*. Мы
>   говорили: «я переживаю горе» или «я переживаю радость», а теперь
>   говорят: «я так переживаю» (без дополнения), и это слово означает
>   теперь: «я волнуюсь», а еще чаще: «я страдаю», «я мучаюсь». Такой
>   формы не знали ни Толстой, ни Тургенев, ни Чехов. Для них *переживать*
>   всегда было переходным глаголом».

В вышедшем в 1974 году словаре трудностей  русского языка ***(Вакуров В.Н., Рахманова Л.И. и др. "Трудности русского языка: Словарь-справочник журналиста",  изд. МГУ)*** отмечалась разговорность слова *переживать* и рекомендовалось употребление вместо этого слова в контекстах книжного, официального характера слов "огорчался", "волнуется"…

Этот словарь отмечал, что в значении "волноваться, тревожиться, беспокоиться…" глагол *переживать* в сочетании с винительным падежом нередко употребляется с предлогом ***за***. О других падежах и предлогах в этом словаре речь не шла.

В вышедшем в том же 1974 году словаре ***Горбачевича ("Трудности словоупотребления и варианты норм русского литературного языка")*** приводились примеры конструкций с род. падежом *(**из-за** кого-чего)*, тв. *(**о** ком-чём)* и вин. *(**за** кого-что)* падежами, причём конструкции с тв. и вин. падежами были снабжены пометой ***разг.***

А что рекомендуют современные словари?

Из ***словаря-справочника Розенталя "Управление в русском языке" (М., 2003):***

> ПЕРЕЖИВАТЬ (испытывать волнение, беспокойство в связи с чем-л.,
>   нервничать по поводу чего-л.) ***из-за*** кого-чего / **о** ком-чем
>   **(разг.)** / **за** кого-что **(прост.)**.

***Лазуткина*** в  ***"Словаре грамматической сочетаемости слов русского языка" (2013)*** привела почему-то только варианты с ***за*** кого-что и ***о*** ком-чём.

Но конструкции с ***о*** ком-чём признаются, оказывается, не всеми лингвистами.

Вот что говорится о слове *переживать* в 4-ом издании словаря под ред.
 Рахмановой  ***(Вакуров В.Н., Рахманова Л.И. и др. "Трудности русского
 языка: Словарь-справочник", М., 2011)***:

> Если в контексте указана причина, объект волнения, огорчения, слово
>   *переживать*, согласно литературной норме, употребляется в конструкциях *переживать **из-за** кого (чего)* или *переживать **за**
>   кого (что)*…
>
> **Ошибкой является использование глагола *переживать* в сочетании с предложным падежом с предлогом *о*.**

Comment: Спасибо, slava1947!

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, говорить *переживать из-за экзамена* в любом случае правильно, а *переживать за экзамен* если и допустимо, то только в разговорном стиле, и то ещё вопрос, насколько это оправдано.

Comment: Артём Луговой, ну не решают такие вопросы путем высказываний личных предпочтение. Надо давать источник. Только не как Sergey  - опять не понял того, что сам же нашел.

Comment: Согласен, что подтвердить источником лучше. Но всё же Tagirix сказала почти то же, что и я, значит, не так уж я и неправ.

Comment: Tagirix  - он. )))) И дело не в том, кто что сказал, а в формулировке "однозначно правильно". Можно без аргументации принять существование мнения, но не столь категоричного.

Comment: Ой, прошу прощения (у него в первую очередь)! Почему-то подумал что она.(( Действительно, очень категорично, сейчас изменю.

Comment: Спасибо, Артём!

Answer (score 1):

Правильно (по словарю): **переживать за экзамен и об экзамене.**

Из словаря грамматической сочетаемости слов (2013):

Переживать (волноваться, беспокоиться):

1) За кого/что (с одушевленными и отвлеченными сущ.): переживать за сына, переживать за судьбу проекта.

2) О ком/чём (с одушевленными и отвлеченными сущ.): не переживай о съёмках.

Comment: *Правильно (по словарю): переживать за экзамен и об экзамене.* - нет. По Вашему словарю как раз следует иное. "Экзамен" никак нельзя назвать ни отвлеченным, ни одушевленным.

Comment: А какое это существительное? Всего 4 класса: конкретные, отвлеченные, вещественные, собирательные. Конкретные  обозначают реальные предметы, доступные нашим органам чуств.

Comment: Конкретное, если по этой четырехчленной системе. Только при чем тут органы чувств? Почитайте, что такое конкретные и отвлеченные существительные  http://www.goldrussian.ru/konkretnye-imena-sushhestvitelnye.html#title и http://www.goldrussian.ru/nekonkretnye-otvlechennye-sushhestvitelnye.html (если источник не авторитетен, найду в АГ).

Comment: Экзамен - это проверка знаний, то есть  название действия. А этот вариант вроде бы относится к отвлеченным существительным?

Comment: Ну, знаете... . А множественное число названию действия зачем?  И где Вы вообще нашли это правило про название действия? ***Отвлеченные** (абстрактные) существительные – это слова, называющие **отвлеченные** понятия, свойства, качества, действия и состояния* - (Выделено мой - b-s). АГ - http://rusgram.narod.ru/1121-1146.html  ***Конкретные** существительные - это слова, называющие вещи, лица, факты и все явления действительности, которые **могут быть представлены в отдельности** и подвергнуты счету:* (там же)

Comment: Ну ладно, посчитали: один экзамен, два экзамена. А всё-таки, переживать-то как будете: за экзамен, из-за экзамена или об экзамене? Влияют ли на выбор предлога одушевленность и отвлеченность или что влияет? Почему из "моего словаря" (кстати, он из академической программы "Словари XXI века") исчез предлог ИЗ-ЗА?

Comment: Это, простите, каким образом с вопросом связано? Я "за экзамены" переживал очень сильно. Вот так как-то сложилось, что очень нервным был в молодости. Но что это меняет?

Comment: Жаль, нервы надо было бы поберечь. Просто хотелось услышать ваше мнение: какими предлогами можно пользоваться при переживаниях  и почему? Выбираем из трех предлогов: за, из-за, о/об. Может быть, у них семантика разная?

Comment: ***За***, - кого-что. (в сочет. с глаг.: бояться, волноваться, беспокоиться, радоваться и т.п.). Указывает на лицо, предмет, состояние и т.п., которые вызывают то или иное чувство, переживание. Бояться за чью-л. жизнь. Радоваться за друга.

Comment: ***Из-за*** , -  Лицо, предмет, которые служат поводом к какому-л. действию.

Comment: Так что оба варианта возможны, в зависимости от того, какой смысл вкладывать. Просто первый вариант меньше распространен.

Comment: Да, мне тоже так кажется.  В первом случае мы беспокоимся о чем-то дорогом и близком, а во втором просто указываем на предмет беспокойств и волнений (хотя это тоже может быть нечто дорогое).

Comment: Да, Сергей. Именно так.

Comment: Спасибо, Sergey!

Answer (score 1):

Считаю, что *переживать из-за экзамена* однозначно правильно. Из-за экзамена = по поводу экзамена. Второй вариант, что интересно, я встречаю очень часто, что может говорить как минимум о том, что он принят в обиход, хотя и может быть неправильным (насчет этого, к сожалению, сказать ничего не могу).

Comment: Спасибо, Tagirix!